# Can't automated a Zurb-foundation Drop down list using Selenium2 webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, zurb-foundation

Currently I am having an issue trying to select an item in a drop down list using selenium. The drop down list is using zurb-foundation to style the look of the drop down. The first element select `id=customDropdown` (see html below) is a hidden field on the page that is used to build a `data-id=1391787504820-vf4ww`. That data-ID  is then  used by the the div class  `<div class="custom dropdown" large data-id="1391787504820-vf4ww">`.

I could use the `JavascriptExecutor` to make the `id=customDropdown` visible and then use  the `Webdriver Select()` class  to select an option but I am not sure if this the correct way to test this functionality. Since an end user would not really interact with the UI this way, I don't think it would be a valid test. So my question is how can I test this by using  `<div class="custom dropdown" large data-id="1391787504820-vf4ww">`?

When I click on the selector using CSS, the list displays but I am unable to click on anything in the list using CSS or xpath. I get an error that says element not found.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>    
  <h1>The customDropdown ID is a hidden field on that page</h1>
  <div class="columns" style="width: 29.5em;">
    <select id="customDropdown" class="large hidden-field" data-id="1391787504820-vf4ww">
        <option disabled="" class="italics">Company Name 1</option>
        <option class="accountSelectorOpt" value="madeupvalue1">account name 1</option>
        <option class="accountSelectorOpt" value="madeupvalue2">account name 2</option>
        <option class="accountSelectorOpt" value="madeupvalue3">account name 3</option>
        <option class="accountSelectorOpt" value="madeupvalue4">account name 4</option>
        <option class="accountSelectorOpt" value="madeupvalue5">account name 5</option>
        <option disabled="" class="italics">Company Name 2</option>
        <option class="accountSelectorOpt" value="madeupvalue6">account name 6</option>
        <option class="accountSelectorOpt" value="madeupvalue7">account name 7</option>
        <option disabled="" class="italics">Company Name 3</option>
        <option class="accountSelectorOpt" value="madeupvalue8">account name 8</option>
        <option class="accountSelectorOpt" value="madeupvalue9">account name 9</option>
        <option class="accountSelectorOpt" value="madeupvalue10">account name 10</option>
        <option disabled="" class="italics">Company Name 4 Board</option>
        <option class="accountSelectorOpt" value="madeupvalue11">account name11</option>
    </select>

    <h1>The class "custom dropdown large is the Div that dsiplays the drop down list </h1>  
    <div class="custom dropdown large" data-id="1391787504820-vf4ww">
      <a href="#" class="current"></a>
      <a href="#" class="selector"></a>
      <ul>
        <li class="disabled">Company Name 1</li>
        <li class="selected">account name 1</li>
        <li>account name 2</li>
        <li>account name 3</li>
        <li>account name 4</li>
        <li>account name 5</li>
        <li class="disabled">Company Name 2</li>
        <li>account name 6</li>
        <li>account name 7</li>
        <li class="disabled">Company Name 3</li>
        <li>account name 8</li>
        <li>account name 9</li>
        <li>account name 10</li>
        <li class="disabled">Company Name 4</li>
        <li>account name 11</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like the example below.  First look through the entire DOM for anything that has account name 1. Then loop through the results looking for one that is visible. Last if possible, click on the element.  You could also put this in a wait for loop in case it is taking a little bit of time to display the element.

```
var elementsArray = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//.[text()=\"account name 1\"]")).toArray();
for (var i = 0; i < elementsArray.length; i++) {
     if (elementsArray[i].isDisplayed()) {
          var element = elementsArray[i];
     }
}
if(element){
     element.click();
}
```

Brian Kranson
Neustar, Inc. / Professional Services Engineer

Answer (score 0):

we have several products using this to simulate the dropdown.

my solution is,

1. click on the outside div item , it's `//div[@class='custom dropdown large']` in your case
2. after that, the options listed inside `<ul>` tag will display.
3. then click on the `<li>` item which has your wanted option